# Magento Multistore : redirecting non www to www

Tags: magento

We are running Magento CE 1.6.2 and we would like to run another store. We had correctly configured store2.com but we have a problem :

store1.com redirect to www.store1.com : OK
store2.com and www.store2.com redirect to www.store1.com : NOT OK

Here is our .htaccess :

```
SetEnvIf Host .*store2.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2_com
SetEnvIf Host .*store2.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
```

To redirect non www to www we are using :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This config doesn't work.

We run store2.com with a parked domain and sharing hosting between store1.com and store2.com.

Hope you can help us and sorry for my english.

Thank you for your help
Quentin

Answer (score 1):

1) ensure that all domains points to same document root

2) in magento backend specify base url for each store/website you run (if they are different)

3) amend index.php choose correct store/website based on domain

in our index.php we have something like this

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'www.example.com':
      $mageRunCode = 'www_exampe_com';
      break;  
    case 'another.example.com':
      $mageRunCode = 'another_example_com';
      break;        
    case 'admin.example.com':  
      $mageRunCode = 'admin';
      break;  
    default:
      $mageRunCode = 'www_example_com';      
  }

}

Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

where www_example_com, another_example_com are store codes specified in System > Stores management.

**Update:**
Also I found this tutorial http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup so it can be helpful but you need to update your virtual host setup and it might not to be suitable solution in certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the Magento admin configuration pages? Go to `System -> Configuration -> Web` then change the `Configuration Scope` to the `store2` website equivalent. Expand the `Unsecure` section and input `http://www.store2.com` on the Base URL field. Do the same for the Secure section if you plan to use SSL and use `https://www.store2.com/`.

[image: System->Configuration->Web section Magento Admin]

Also please note that you cannot use {{base_url}} anymore on Magento 1.6.x.